# PDE Headless Build (Feature-based) and Missing Required Plug-ins

Tags: plugins, ant, eclipse-pde, headless, pde

When attempting to perform a PDE headless build, I am finding the *eclipse.buildScript* step to display the following:

```
[java] generateScript:
[java] [eclipse.buildScript] Some inter-plug-in dependencies have not been satisfied.
[java] [eclipse.buildScript] Bundle org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.design.ui:
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.profile_[3.0.6,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.design_[3.0.4,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer_[3.1.1,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript] Bundle org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.profile:
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer_[3.1.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript] Bundle org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.templates:
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.pde.ui_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.pde.ui.templates_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript] Bundle org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.jdt.classpath:
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.jdt.ui_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript] Bundle org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.ws.ui:
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.design.ui_[3.0.6,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml.ui_[1.1.0,2.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript] Bundle org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.ws:
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Another singleton version selected: org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.ws_1.1.2.v200812171046
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Optional plug-in org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.profile_[3.0.4,4.0.0) is not available.
[java] [eclipse.buildScript] Bundle org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml.ui:
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.design.ui_[3.0.6,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript] Bundle org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml.ui:
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.design.ui_[3.0.6,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript] Bundle org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml:
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Another singleton version selected: org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml_1.1.2.v200902111040
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Optional plug-in org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.profile_[3.0.4,4.0.0) is not available.
[java] [eclipse.buildScript] Bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui:
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.help_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.core.expressions_[3.4.100,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.core.resources_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.core.variables_[3.2.200,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.search_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.debug.core_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.debug.ui_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.jdt.launching_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.compare_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.team.ui_[3.4.100,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.team.core_[3.4.100,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.jface.text_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.ui_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.ui.console_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.ui.ide_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.ui.views_[3.3.100,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.ui.editors_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.core.runtime_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_[3.4.100,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.ui.forms_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.ui.navigator_[3.3.200,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.jdt.core.manipulation_[1.3.0,2.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript] Bundle org.eclipse.pde.ui.templates:
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.pde.ui_[3.3.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript] Bundle org.eclipse.pde.ui:
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.pde.core_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.jface.text_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.debug.ui_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.jdt.launching_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.jdt.ui_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.pde.build_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.search_[3.1.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.team.core_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.ui_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.ant.ui_[3.1.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.jdt.junit_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.compare_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui_[1.0.0,2.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata_[1.0.0,2.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine_[1.0.100,2.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core_[1.0.0,2.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director_[1.0.100,2.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository_[1.0.100,2.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository_[1.0.100,2.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.equinox.frameworkadmin_[1.0.100,2.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.equinox.frameworkadmin.equinox_[1.0.100,2.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Missing required plug-in org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository_[1.0.0,2.0.0).
[java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Unsatisfied import package org.eclipse.jdt.debug.core_0.0.0.
```

I understand that these bundles / plug-ins are missing required and / or optional dependencies.  what I do not understand is how certain plug-ins are NOT found.

For example, there are many org.eclipse.XXXXX plug-ins listed, which I believe would be resolved through the use of the *baseLocation* property, which I have set as follows:

```
<full_path_from_root>\pdebuild\target\eclipse
```

Where eclipse is my target to build against and has all of my third-party dependencies.

In addition, I also have a separate eclipse install that serves as the version initiating the build (e.g., version 3.5.2 with PDE build files).  The "plugins" sub-folder in this eclipse does have the missing dependencies listed above.

Thus, when attempting resolve missing dependencies, be they either required or optional, how are they resolved during a headless PDE build?  I find it odd that I would have to copy the missing plug-ins from the eclipse used to initiate the headless PDE build over into the target\eclipse\plugins sub-folder, just to attempt to resolve this issue.  When I do this though, I receive even more "missing required plug-in" messages.  Maybe this just boils down to me having to continue copying the libraries over into my target\eclipse\plugins sub-folder until the messages disappear.

Many thanks to those who can offer any advice or suggestions as to how best to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify the base location, either using an eclipse install as your target or a set of p2 repos, that defines what PDE build will build against.  The eclipse used to initiate your build using ant (we refer to that as the basebuilder) has no effect on what is being built.

But if your baseLocation points to a complete eclipse install that contains all of the plugins, it should work.  Is your baseLocation a valid eclipse install, or just a dumping ground for plugins and features?

Comment: Thanks Paul for your reply.  The baseLocation value is pointing to a valid eclipse 3.4.2 installation and is actually stored in SVN for automated build purposes.  When attempting to prepare the build environment, this version of eclipse is obtained from SVN and parked in the `${buildDirectory}/target/eclipse` sub-folder.